# Python shutdown node

Tags: ros, python, rospy, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How i can shutdown a node in python?
In c++ is ros::shutdown() but in python i didn't find it.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218240/python-shutdown-node/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you set the `disable_signals` parameter in `rospy.init_node` to `True` then you can manually shutdown the node with a call to `rospy.signal_shutdown(reason)` where reason is a String with the reason for shutdown.

For more information check out this wiki http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown or the rospy API http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/

---

Originally posted by [robocop](https://answers.ros.org/users/31127/robocop/) with karma: 76 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5